# compute the complex-valued integral for the branch cut

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, contour-integration, branch-cuts

Let $C$ be the circle of radius $2$ centered at origin. Let $f(z)$ be the
branch cut of the function $z^{2−i}$ on the domain $−π < θ < π$. Compute
the integral
$$ \int_C f(z) dz$$

My attempt:

$f(z) = z^{2−i} = e^{(2-i)logz} $
$C$ is defined as $2e^{i\theta}$ on the interval $−π < θ < π$

so we get: $\int_C f(z) dz = \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{(2-i)(\ln2 + i\theta)}*2ie^{i\theta} d\theta $

Does this look right? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: that's $r$ the magnitude of $2-i$

Comment: Given your parametrization, $\log z = \ln 2 + i\theta$, not $\ln \sqrt{5} + i\theta$.

Comment: Alright, so do I just solve the integral then?

Comment: Yes, now evaluate the integral.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help.